# Arduino button LED not working

Tags: arduino

When I push the button it turns the KY008 off but when I click it again it won't turn it off, but if I jiggle the Laser Diode a little bit the KY008 turns back on.

Code:

```cpp
int LED = 12;
int BUTTON = 4;

void setup(){
   pinMode(LED,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(BUTTON,INPUT);
}

void loop(){
    if(digitalRead(BUTTON) == HIGH){
        digitalWrite(LED,HIGH);
    }else{ 
    digitalWrite(LED,LOW);
    }
}
```

Comment: a) Read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to learn how to format your code. b) Consider posting at [arduino.se]

Comment: Do you have external pullup/pulldown resistors?

Comment: Also KY008 seems to be a laser module not a LED.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `INPUT` you need to have a physical pullup (or pulldown) resistor (typically 10k).

Otherwise use `INPUT_PULLUP` to use the Arduino internal pullup resistors

```
pinMode(BUTTON, INPUT_PULLUP);
```

Make sure that your button closes the circuit to ground when pressed.

Also when reading a button you will have a lot of bouncing.
The easiest way to prevent the bouncing is to add a delay between reads.

```
void loop(){
    if(digitalRead(BUTTON) == HIGH){
        digitalWrite(LED,HIGH);
    }else{ 
        digitalWrite(LED,LOW);
    }
    delay(100);
}
```