# Arduino Micro keyboard

Tags: button, arduino, keyboard

I'm trying to make a keyboard with my Arduino Micro. Circuit is OK but I having some issues with the code and hope you can gimme a hand here. For now I'm just trying with one key in pin 8 that should open a new tab in the web browser when you press the button. Just one key for now to see if it works.

I have this code:

```cpp
#include <Keyboard.h>

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(8, INPUT);
  Keyboard.begin(); // setup keyboard
}

void loop() {
  // check buttons
  if (readButton(8)) {
    doAction(8);
  }
}

boolean readButton(int pin) {
  // check and debounce buttons
  if (digitalRead(pin) == HIGH) {
    delay(10000);
    if (digitalRead(pin) == HIGH) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

void doAction(int pin) {
  // perform tasks
  switch (pin) {
    case 8:
      // CMD + T (new tab, Chrome)
      Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_GUI);
      Keyboard.press('t');
      delay(10000);
      Keyboard.releaseAll();
      break;

  }
}
```

But once I upload the code it starts opening new tabs automatically for 10 seconds and then stops for another 10 seconds and starts again. All this without pressing the button, it does it automatically. Any idea what I have wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arduino button LED not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48646503/arduino-button-led-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

You're using `Keyboard.press()` which according to the documentation

> When called, `Keyboard.press()`functions as if a key were pressed and held on your keyboard.

That is, you're pressing and holding the key. And so the Arduino keeps sending the key sequence `CMD + T (new tab, Chrome)` to your PC and thus Chrome will keep opening new tabs.

You need to `release` after giving enough delay so that you send only one key press to the application.

> To end the key press, use `Keyboard.release()` or `Keyboard.releaseAll()`.

The 10 second is evident from the `delay(10000)` you've used.

Comment: Hi clmno, many thanks for the message. I understand what you say, however the main issue is that arduino do the action without pressing (or releasing) any button. it just run the program automatically as soon as is uploaded to the board.

Comment: @tanaan Have you pulled up the pin?

Comment: yup, with a 10k resistor. is that what you mean?

Comment: @tanaan What happens when you press the button? Does the pin get pulled down (0V) or does the pin get pulled up? You've written a code that detects a `pull-up`.

Comment: @tanaan I was asking with respect the the voltage and not the code. Use a multimeter to understand the connectivity. If the connections are all right and if the program runs when no button press event is seen then most prob'ly you've wired it to be pulled up by default causing the prog to think it's a `HIGH` event and run the rest of the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179741/discussion-between-clmno-and-tanaan).